# How do I use the java library "HTML Parser" to remove all <style> tags?

Tags: java, html, parsing, tags

I need to perform several action on a html file such as removing a specific tag or delete attributes. I decided to use HTML Parser, a java library:
http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

First of all, I want to remove all the style tags. I managed to get a NodeList containing all the styles tag by doing this:

```
Parser parser = new Parser (url);
NodeList list = parser.parse (null);            
NodeList styles = list.extractAllNodesThatMatch (new TagNameFilter ("STYLE"), true);
```

Now I don't know how to delete this style attributes from the whole list of nodes. Do I have to fetch the whole list?

After that, I want to be able to delete all the attributes inside the tags or delete only the alt attributes for example. Is there a method which does that automatically?

Comment: If you can guarantee that you HTML will be XML-valid (if necessary through HTML Purifier or something similar) you should use an XML parser, as they are far more powerful (being able to use XPath would make many of your tasks trivial).

Comment: +1 for a well-written first question. It's rare to be able to read and understand a user's first question. Well done, and good luck on Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation, the `Parser` returns a list of trees that contains all of your html's nodes (think of the parser as the root node of a big tree of `Node` and each "level" of that tree is a `NodeList`).

You can iterate through the tree recursively, test each node's type against `StyleTag` and delete it from the appropriate `NodeList` when applicable. Keep descending into the tree recursively until you visit all its nodes.

`NodeTreeWalker` is your friend and can help you with the recursive tree traversal.

[jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is another nice alternative that has a simpler interface (see this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357855/extract-and-clean-html-fragment-using-html-parser-org-htmlparser)).

Comment: I stopped trying with HTMLParser and I have switched to JSoup which is much simpler, you were right about that. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. If you found this to be the correct answer, please don't forget to mark it as such. :-)