# remove html tags with using StringTokenizer

Tags: java, html, tags

Here is my string:

```
String str = "<pre><font size="5"><strong><u>LVI . The Day of Battle</u></strong></font>        
<font
size="4"><strong>";
```

I want to remove all html tags in a string with using `StringTokenizer`. But I don't understand how to use StringTokenizer for this situation. Because when I use `str.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","")`, it is not efficient to remove all tags because some tags will be on the next line of string, as seen the string above. But I want to do it for all situations between `<` and `>`. How can I do it? (I want to achieve it  using `StringTokenizer`). Thanks..

Comment: A) You shouldn't be using `StringTokenizer`. As the docs state, it's a legacy class. B) Attempting to parse HTML with regex is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @BrianRoach There's another library for removing html tags JSon, but I am not be able to use other libraries, and it seems there is no other way to fulfill it.

Comment: Why can't you use other libraries?

Comment: @DNA Because it's actually my lab assignment and I will not be able to use another things...

Comment: Does the assigment say you have to use StringTokenizer, or just that you can't use external libraries?

Comment: we shouldn't use external libraries, but we don't have to use only StringTokenizer, but I don't find any specific and efficient solution for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to process HTML with regexes or `StringTokenizer` alone is... painful.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) is compulsory reading before you go any further.

If your HTML files are simple, you *might* get away with removing the newlines, then applying a regex, then reformatting the HTML - or try multiline regexes.

But you should really look at using a proper HTML parser. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592418/how-do-i-use-the-java-library-html-parser-to-remove-all-style-tags) (and probably many others...)

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you shouldn't parse HTML with anything except an HTML parsing library.  Writing your own parser creates a security risk and exposes your applications to possible attack vectors like Cross Site Scripting and various other bugs.  Again: don't parse HTML with regex or a simple tokenizer.  An exception to this rule may be if you have a small set of known HTML data inputs and you will use your code on that data **only**.  In this scenario, you can and should verify that your code is doing the correct thing for each input.

That said, your original regex is very close.  The dot wildcard matches everything except newlines, and so if we add to your regex the possibility of newlines in addition to the dot wildcard, we get positive results on your test string.

```
String result = str.replaceAll("<(.|\r|\n|\f)*?>","");
```

**DO NOT USE THIS CODE ON UNKNOWN INPUT!  DO NOT USE IT IN PRODUCTION!  IT IS NOT A SAFE OR CORRECT APPROACH TO PARSING HTML.**

Comment: +1 for properly warning about parsing HTML with regex (need I include the [obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/960195)?).  However, cross site scripting is a specific class of bugs in which an attacker is able to trick the user's browser into *executing* malicious code (usually JavaScript).  Simply parsing HTML doesn't open you up to XSS because you aren't executing anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use an HTML parser library instead of StringTokenizer. Please have a look at the below demonstration:

1. Download jsoup-1.6.1.jar core library from http://jsoup.org/download.
2. Add this library to your classpath.
3. Play with your HTML as you like. Example below is the code for converting HTML content to text format:

   import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

   public class HtmlParser {

   ```
   public static String removeAllHtml(String htmlContent) {
       return Jsoup.parse(htmlContent).text();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String htmlContent = "<pre><font size=\"5\"><strong><u>LVI . The Day of Battle</u></strong></font><fontsize=\"4\"><strong>";
       System.out.println(removeAllHtml(htmlContent));
   }
   ```

   }