# I want to remove script and a tags from jsoup element

Tags: java, jsoup

I have following in element
element value;

```html
org.jsoup.nodes.Element value=<div>
                  <h1>Harry potter and deathly hallows<h1>
                  some Info........
                  <a href="http://www.hp.com">greate person</a>
                  <a href="http://www.hp2.com">cast</a>
                  <script>
some function
                  </script>
                  </div>
```

I want to remove all  and 
so that my value becomes

```html
org.jsoup.nodes.Element value=<div>
                  <h1>Harry potter and deathly hallows<h1>
                  some Info........
                  </div>
```

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8358446/2830834

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it, first I converted it into `Document` and then removed

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(value.toString());
doc.select("a,script,.hidden,style,form,span").remove();
```

This is link for full answer : [Extract and Clean HTML Fragment using HTML Parser (org.htmlparser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357855/extract-and-clean-html-fragment-using-html-parser-org-htmlparser?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this following snippet:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(value);//value is your variable having html content

System.out.println(doc.text());//gives you plain text
```

Want to select one element:

```
doc.select("h1").text();
```

Comment: Actually that value is of element type. sorry for inconvinience.

Answer (score 0):

```
String html = "<p> <span> some </span> <em> text<a> sometext </a> sometext</em> </p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String textContent=doc.text();
```

To know more refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8358446/2830834)

If you want learn more please gone through [jsoup cookbook at official site](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) here.

Comment: actually that value is Element

Comment: you mean you only need <div><h1>some info..</h1></div> as value?